# Character eyes are black

Tags: materials, shaders

I made a pair of eyes for a character of mine that consists of two meshes. One that acts as the real eye with the iris and the pupil, and then a copy of that one but slightly different to represent a cornea which has only a simple glass shader on. Why are the eyes of my character dark as soon as I place them inside the eye sockets? Seriously, you can barely see them. Can anyone tell me why Blender does this?

Eye out of socket:

[image]

Eye inside socket:

[image]

From a distance you can't see it's eyes at all, only if you're this close can you make them out.

Blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vj7jwmcu7sn7bej/Dark%20Eyes.blend?dl=0

Comment: Try to increase the Transmission and Glossy bounces.

Comment: It became a bit clearer but it's still too dark. I wanted them to be vibrant, almost like sapphires.

Comment: Can you attach the .blend please

Comment: I added a dropbox link to the blend file on the post.

Comment: You probably need to pack the textures into the .blend, can't see them. EDIT: whoops, sorry, it seems only the World-HDR image was missing.

Comment: For me it looks like only a lighting-issue. More light to the eye-side should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to see it all without all the pictures packed (or I just don't have HDR activated), or that the head is lacking materials. However, I myself have had a few troubles in regards to things being not lit the way I like it. One of the things involves having specularity spots on eyes even in a dimly lit room. The two options I came up with was having "virtual lights" (spot and point) surrounding the face, and having a starfield texture added as emission.

I have played around a bit with your node setup, and what I've come up with is that from the `Mix` node that is connected to the `Principled`'s `Base Color`, add a connection to a `Bright/Contrast` node, connect that to an `Ambient Occlusion` shader, and then an `Add` shader that adds together the `Principled` and `Ambient` outputs to the `Material Output`.

With the `Bright/Contrast` node you can control how bright/vibrant you want your eye, seeing as `AO` (and `Add`) doesn't have a slider for how much it affects the material. If you want a "strength slider" for the shader, or don't mind the eye emitting some light, you can exchange the `AO` shader for an `Emission` shader.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This did help and now I can see the eye clearly but it looks flat.

Comment: At least it is a start. Play around with what I've given you, exchange or add some nodes, or connect them differently. Hopefully you'll achieve the result you are looking for.